# Android. Не реагирует кнопка на нажатие в Canvas

Tags: java, android, button

Есть кнопка, созданная и отображена в Canvas, но при нажатии она не реагирует и не вызывается всплывающее сообщение. Что тут можно изменить, чтобы заработал слушатель? Есть еще особенность: кнопка отображена, но при нажатии , визуально не изменяется (как будто она за стеклом и палец к ней не доходит). Может нужно какой то порядок изменить холст-кнопка/кнопка-холст?

```
public class ButtonInCanvas extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button = new Button(ButtonInCanvas.this);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setText("OK!");
        setContentView(new BtInCanvas(ButtonInCanvas.this));
    }


    public class BtInCanvas extends View {
        public BtInCanvas(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            button.layout(50,50,300,300);
            button.draw(canvas);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"OK!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно установить листенер на `new BtInCanvas(ButtonInCanvas.this)` а не на `Button` который по идеии вообще не должен отображаться на экране!

Я этот код не запускал, но возможно, вам нужно что то, типа этого:

```
public class ButtonInCanvas extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        BtInCanvas btInCanvas = new BtInCanvas(ButtonInCanvas.this);

        btInCanvas.setOnClickListener(this);
        btInCanvas.setText("OK!");

        setContentView(btInCanvas);
    }


    public class BtInCanvas extends View {
        public BtInCanvas(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            button.layout(50,50,300,300);
            button.draw(canvas);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"OK!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```