# Кнопка в Canvas android

Tags: java, android, button, android-canvas

Вопрос в следующем: есть draw_activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity.DrawView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/drawView"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:text="back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Есть DrawActivity

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));
        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /** Интент для перехода на экран ввода точек */
                Intent drawActivity = new Intent(DrawActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(drawActivity);
            }
        });
    }
```

В `DrawView` отрисовывается круг по заданным точкам. Под ним хочу сделать кнопку возврата в активити, где изначально вводятся координаты точек. Не получается ни увидеть кнопку, ни инициализировать ее.

Что делаю не так, может кто подскажет как лучше создать кнопку на `Canvas`?

Класс DrawView с конструктором (методы и onDraw не показываю, они работают, проверено)

```
//переменные класса DrawActivity
public int width;
public int height;
public float cx;
public float cy;
public float[] coordinates;

class DrawView extends View {
    /** Задаем переменные класса
     *  р - кисть для фигур
     *  рТ - кисть для текста
     *  rectF - рамка для подписей точек
     *  radius - радиус окружности
     *  tk - коэффициент отношения длины половины экрана к радиусу окружности
     */
    Paint p;
    Paint pT;
    Rect rect;
    RectF rectF;
    float radius, tk;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        p = new Paint();
        pT = new Paint();
        rectF = new RectF();
        //получение ширины и высоты экрана
        initWidthAndHeight(context);
        cx = intent.getFloatExtra("cx", 0);
        cy = intent.getFloatExtra("cy", 0);
        coordinates = intent.getFloatArrayExtra("coord");
        // получаем радиус окружности
        getDistance();
        // получаем коэффициент соотношения ширины экрана к радиусу окружности
        tk = (float) 0.8 * ((width / 2) / radius);
    }
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560908/177345 ?

Answer (score 2):

У вас на экране только DrawView.

```
setContentView(new DrawView(this));
```

В этот метод нужно передать Layout который вы хотите отобразить.
Вот так:

```
setContentView(R.layout.draw_activity);
```

**UPD 12.09.2016**

1) Проверьте чтобы у вас стояли нужные модификаторы перед классом DrawView

> public  **static**  class DrawView

Поскольку это у вас внутренний класс класса DrawActivity.

2)Не забудьте добавить нужные конструкторы, а именно :

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

**UPD 15.09.2016 Как получить доступ к getIntent из `static DrawView`**
Чтобы получить доступ к `getIntent` напишите к конструкторе следующее:

```
public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Intent intent = ((Activity)context)getIntent();
....
}
```

Comment: Когда я вызываю Layout, как Вы показали то получается ошибка  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.threepointscircle/com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity.DrawView      DrawView как показано у меня отрабатывает нормально

Comment: 1 ) У вас перед классом DrawView стоят модификаторы "public static" ?
2) в классе DrawView у все присутствуют все нужные конструкторы ?
А именно :
<code>
public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);      
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);        
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);        
    }
</code>

Comment: Описал более детально в самом ответе на вопрос (см. UPD 12.09.2016).

PS Хорошо было бы увидеть полный код DrawActivity.

Comment: в вопросе добавил конструктор моего DrawView. Если ставлю ему модификатор static, то тогда не могу использовать Intent.

Comment: Фраза "не могу использовать Intent" скорее всего означала то, что вам нужна ссылка на инстанс DrawActivity. Если это так, то её легко получить следующим образом :  (DrawActivity )this.getContext().   

Если фраза означала иное то опишите детальнее - в чем проблема.

Comment: нет, не поэтому, просто getIntent - не статический метод. Пробовал создать кнопку в onDraw, но выдает, что нельзя разрешить метод setBounds. Замкнутый круг какой-то.

Comment: Описал как получить доступ к `getIntent` из `static DrawView` в ответе на вопрос (см UPD 15.09.2016 )

Comment: это ничего не меняет - Не статический метод 'getIntent' не может быть вызван из статического контекста