# Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android

Что означает эта ошибка?
Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class

нигде не могу найти нормального объяснения

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity.DrawView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/drawView"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:text="back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Выше - разметка

Вот начало класса. Ошибка возникает при подключении листенера

```
public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.draw_activity);
        Button backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /** Интент для перехода на отрисовку результатов просчета*/
                Intent drawActivity = new Intent(DrawActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(drawActivity);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: У вас какая-то ошибка в разметке видимо. Покажите эту разметку

Comment: Я подозреваю, что присутсвует какой-то запрещенный символ.

Comment: А ещё там может быть неправильно или не полно класс прописан. Или либа не подключена

Comment: Добавил разметку

Comment: Я точно не уверен, то вроде нельзя использовать слеши в атрибутах. Вместо них есть спец символы...

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно) По крайней мере у меня всегда это работало)

Comment: @iluxa1810, какие слеши в атрибутах имеются ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите указать в разметке виджет класса являющегося чьим-то внутренним классом, то разделять классы надо символом `$` вместо точки

Т.е. в вашем случае запись должна быть

```
<com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity$DrawView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/drawView"/>
```

Либо попробуйте так:

```
<view 
   class="com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity$DrawView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/drawView"/>
```

Comment: Если делаю так, то IDE ругается, что начальный тэг не закрыт. (Tag start is not closed)

Comment: @Velsevool, обновил ответ

Comment: Если применяю второй вариант, то получаю ошибку Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.example.android.threepointscircle.DrawActivity$DrawView

Comment: @Velsevool, попробуйте его в отдельный файл вынести и оба способа попробовать. Если всё одно падать будет то проблема может оказаться в самом классе.

Comment: спасибо. Попробую, по результату отпишусь. Но должен отметить, что ошибка выскакивает, когда я пытаюсь листенер для кнопки подключить. Без него все работает ОК. Ссылка на мой первый вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564426/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-canvas-android

Comment: @Velsevool, с этого и надо было начинать... Покажите, что ли, класс ваш...

Comment: поместил начало класса в вопрос. Ошибка выскакивает, если вношу в код backButton.setOnClickListener  и т.д. Что делаю не так?

Comment: @Velsevool, хм... у меня нет других идей кроме как класс в отдельный файл вынести. Возможно, так хотя бы ошибка изменится)

Comment: какой класс имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Velsevool, который вашу вьюху описывает. Который вы в разметку добавить пытаетесь

Comment: но он и так отдельным файлом сделан. Там прорисовываю в Canvas круг по трем точкам и хочу сделать кнопку возврата на начальный экран, где эти точки вводятся. Все отрисовывается ОК, а вот эта долбаная кнопка никак показываться и работать не хочет. Вынос мозга какой-то(

Comment: @Velsevool, я запутался. Вы хотите сказать, что ваша кастомная вьюха работает и отображается до тех пор, пока вы рядом с ней не поместите кнопку и не повесите на неё слушатель нажатий?.. 0_о Это звучит невероятно) Может у вас просто студия глючит из-за включённой InstantRun настройки студии?

Comment: да, именно это я и хочу сказать) Все работает и в эмуляторе и в железе. Но до тех пор, пока я не подключаю листенер. Кнопку тоже не видно, но без листенера этого все работает. В главном активити аналогичный листенер для перехода в эту вьюху отрабатывает без проблем, а тут беда какаяд-то

Comment: @Velsevool, может кнопки не видно, т.к. у вас в разметке этой активити её и нет и падает в итоге по NPE из-за этого? И вы не ответили про OnstantRun

Comment: да Вы правы. InstantRun включен. А кнопка в разметке активити есть.

Comment: @Velsevool, попробуйте отключить эту очень плохую функцию

Comment: отключил. Ошибка все та же и кнопки как не было видно, так и нет(((

Comment: @Velsevool, ну, если `build-clean` проекта не поможет, как и перезапуск студии, то вам останется только с нуля всё это ещё раз написать. Ибо, если вы десйствительно загружаете правильную разметку, а имеющаяся в ней кнопка не отображается, то это какой-то фатальный и невоспроизводимый глюк.

Comment: печально. Огромное спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно эта кнопка у вас хранится в отдельном лэйауте, если так то вам нужно получить View при помощи LayoutInflater. После чего в этом View искать по id кнопку и присваивать ей листнер.

```
Button backButton = (Button) myltInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_layout, null, false).findViewById(R.id.btn);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //
        }});
```

В дальнейшем работать с этим View